# Why I cannot install SDK Platform for Android API 30?

Tags: android, api, installation, sdk

[image]

I use Android SDK Manager on my KUbuntu 18.04 workstation. At previous cases all new SDKs were installed as well. Not I try install SDK for API 30 but... just do not see it. At Friday I tried first time - and have got lots of errors in Manager's log. Now log is clean, no errors. But no SDK 30 too. I only see latest SDK Platform Android R Preview. How can I update my apps to API 30 if I cannot install SDK?

Comment: HELP!!! I open Android SDK Manager every day. No errors in log. But SDK 30 still is not availble. How can I develope apps for Android 10 without SDK??? May be I need add some XML files manually? But I cannot find what I have to add.